# Google App Engine の認証方法について

Tags: google-app-engine

Google App Engine の Tutorial に従って
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/quickstart#deploy_your_app

```
gcloud app deploy  --project $my_project_name
```

とするとローカルで動かしたコードが実際に`deploy`されたのですが、この`deploy`時に使われる認証の情報はどこに保存されているのでしょうか？

チュートリアル中で認証に関しての設定をしていなかったはずなんですが…。以前一度チュートリアルをやった時に設定したのかもしれませんが覚えておらず、教えて頂けると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

たぶんどっかのタイミングで `gcloud auth login` していると思います。
その時の認証情報でデプロイしています。
どの認証情報を使っているかは `gcloud auth list` で確認できますのでためしてみてください。

ちなみに、実際に認証したアクセストークンなどのファイルは `$HOME/.config/gcloud` にあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`gcloud auth list`で認証情報を確認できました。プロジェクトフォルダに隠しファイルもないし不思議だったのですが、ユーザーのホームに置いてあったのですね。